# mySQL sum multiple rows and rank handling ties

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
  userid  compid round score    bonus
  2980    3     0     50          0
  50        3     0     80          0
  52        3     0     80          0
  55        3     0     20          0
  58        3     0     100         0
  106      3     0     120         0
  555      3     0     50          0
  100     3     0     30          0
  50        3     1     90          0
  52        3     1     50          0
  106      3     1     30          0
```

I want to be able to not only sum the score and bonus cols per user for all rounds, but rank them accordingly. It should be able to handle ties with the sequence 1,2,2,4,5,5,5,8:

Trick is I don't want to create a temp table or insert the ranking into the table. Also, i can not limit the return - so it need to rank the entire table regardless of rounds completed.

I have managed to rank the rows but can't seem to group them with the sum. And of course I have managed the sum separately - I just need to 'join' the two steps.

Obtaining sums per user:

```
SELECT userid,sum(score+bonus) as tscore from entries 
group by userid order by tscore desc

userid  tscore
50      170
106    150
52      130
58      100
2980      50
555    50
100    30
55        20
```

rank without the score sum : (thanks MySQL Cookbook)

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row,
@rank := IF(@prev_val!=score,@rownum,@rank) AS rank,
userid,
@prev_val := score AS score
FROM exodus_entries ORDER BY score DESC

row   rank  userid      score
1      1    106         120
2      2    58          100
3      3    50          90
4      4    50          80
5      4    52          80
6      6    52          50
7      6    555         50
8      6    2980        50
9      9    100         30
10    9     106         30
11    11    55          20
```

Thanks for the time and help! All advice welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row,
    @rank := IF(@prev_val!=score,@rownum,@rank) AS rank,
    userid,
    @prev_val := score AS score
FROM (
    SELECT userid, sum(score+bonus) as score 
    from entries 
    group by userid 
) exodus_entries 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Kakao!! Works like a charm. Just want to add, should you use the code exactly like above you will see [BLOB - 0B] in your fields, don't forget to set the vars to nul 

    `SET @rownum = 0, @rank = 0, @prev_val = NULL;`

Comment: Found this answer: one note - I had to add the lines 'set @rownum=0; set @rank=0;' (without the single quotes) before the 1st line to get this to work - otherwise rownum and rank were not calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I executed 
`SET @rownum = 0, @rank = 1, @prev_val = NULL;`

before running the following codes:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row,
@rank := IF(@prev_val!=total_number,@rownum,@rank) AS rank,
your_column,
@prev_val := total_number AS total_number
FROM your_table ORDER BY total_number DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT userid,round, sum(score+bonus) as tscore from entries 
group by userid, round order by tscore desc
```

Not tested though.

Comment: Hi Arjan, thank you - but this does not work:

round displays as 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, and it also does not sum per user.

Comment: Guess I misread the question, you only want one row per user. You could use PHP (or whatever other language you are using) to determine the rank and row number, but I think that might not be the best solution.

Comment: No prob - Kakao managed to help me flange it together using pure SQL. Thanks for the help.